# How do I set a value on a specific reactive form control?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form group with a few radio form controls.  One radio for photo, drone, floorplan, etc.

`this.services.photo` for instance is an array of services.  Each radio group lets you select an option from each.  Ie, 1 photo choice, 1 drone choice, 1 floorplan choice.

I'm already able to fetch my data from a service but I'm not able to prepopulate the form with the data. How do I loop through my service data collection and set the value of the radio buttons?  What I'm doing now is not working. Or is there a better way to set things up to make it simpler.

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

  public myForm:FormGroup;
  public services;
  stepName = "cart";
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder, private bookerData:BookerService, private settings:FirebaseService, private route:ActivatedRoute, private zone:NgZone) { 
    this.services = this.route.snapshot.data['cartSettings'].services 
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      photo : new FormControl(this.services.photo),
      drone: new FormControl(this.services.drone),
      floorplan: new FormControl(this.services.floorplan),
      video: new FormControl(this.services.video)

    })
    if(this.bookerData.isValidStep(this.stepName)){
      let data = this.bookerData.getStepData(this.stepName)
      console.log(data);

      _.forOwn(data, (v, k)=>{
        this.myForm.get(k).patchValue(v)
      })
    }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FormControl constructor accepts an 'initial state' value you could use.

```
email: new FormControl('default value', Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
        ])),
```

if your data comes later than initiation (ngOnInit) I would suggest an [ngModel binding](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel), to update an value when you get the form data.